# Powershell variable interrogation of date & time difference

Tags: powershell

Morning All,

I have a variable as follows: `$machines = $user2,$name,$serial,$purchased`
sample data stored in $machines is:

```
User1,
Laptop1,
xyz1234,
01/01/2010
```

I am wanting to create a new variable called $tobereplaced containing all of the records in $machines with a date greater than 4 years old from todays date.

the fuzzy logic code for this im expecting to be someting like `$tobereplaced = $machines.$purchased | where {$_$purchased = -getdate > 4 years}` etc etc but i cant quite figure it out.

Assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$fourYearsAgo = (Get-Date).AddYears(-4) 
$tobereplaced = $machines | Where-Object { (Get-Date $_[-1]) -le $fourYearsAgo }
```

Comment: I am trying to implement this code but $machines contains 4 variables in total so I was hoping to parse the $purchased variable of $machines into a new variable if the date is greater than 4 years ago. My date format is 18/03/2009 but $fouryears ago is 11 September 2008 13:15:50. I am going to have 500 or so rows in $machines and wish to store the 100 or so records that have $purchased variable within $machines over 4 years ago in another variable.

Comment: Are all values string? I suggest you create new object for each row with corresponding (casted) properties so you can filter objects more easily.

Comment: $purchased is populated with the following code so it should be a datetime, the rest are strings -- $dt = [datetime]::ParseExact($prog2,"yyyy/MM/dd",$null)
$purchased = Get-Date $dt -Format 'dd/MM/yyyy'

Comment: I suggest to build custom objects per row and not formatting the dates to strings so you can further filter objects based on the value of the date: New-Object PSObject -Property @{ User = ...; Name = ...; Serial = ...; Purchased = ...; }

Comment: I am trying the following code: if([DateTime]::Parse($machines[4],"dd/MM/yyyy") -le [DateTime]::Now.AddYear(-1)) 
{
  $tobereplaced += $machines
} But $machines[4] is just the 4th char of the string, how do I store the 4 string variables in a seperate columns as I am populating $machines like this: $machines = ($name + " " + $serial + " " + $user2 + " " + $purchased)

Comment: You need to pass a collection: $machines = $name,$serial,$user2,$purchased

Comment: But this is what I recommend doing, so you can refer to value by a property name instead of its index (e.g $machines.purchased )

$machines = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
 Name = $name;
 Serial = $Serial;
 User2 = $user2;
 purchased = $purchased
}

Comment: Ah cool, I have done that now - thanks, however running the following if([DateTime]::Parse($machines.purchased) -le [DateTime]::Now.AddYear(-1)) 
{
  $tobereplaced += $machines
} gives me an error system.datetime doesn't contain a method named addyear.

Comment: i have also tried $fourYearsAgo = (Get-Date).AddYears(-4) 
$tobereplaced = $machines.purchased | Where-Object { (Get-Date $_[-1]) -le $fourYearsAgo} which does work but it still returns the entry if it is less than 4 years ago...

Comment: Now that you custom object you can replace with (Get-Date $_.purchased)

Comment: Excellent thanks, got it working with $fourYearsAgo = (Get-Date).AddYears(-1) 
$tobereplaced = $machines.purchased | Where-Object { (Get-Date $machines.purchased) -le $fourYearsAgo}

Answer (score 1):

Convert the date as DateTime and compare it against a date four years ago. Like so,

```
# Assuming $m[3] contains the timestamp, parse it as a DateTime and compare
# against a date four years ago.
if([DateTime]::Parse($m[3]) -le [DateTime]::Now.AddYear(-4)) {
  $tobereplaced += $m
}
```

Depending on your locale, you might need to tell `[DateTime]::Parse()` how to parse the date. Is 01/12/2010 1st of December, 2010 or 12th January, 2010?

Comment: Is $m[3] the third variable within $m? i.e. if the date is the third record

Comment: If so I am getting String was not recognised as a valid Datetime (im using $machines[4] i.e. $purchased which contains 24/08/2010)

Comment: I am favouring this solution more and would work if I could get the DateTime parse to accept 17/05/2010 etc or convert $purchased to a datetime first.